# cakephp dynamic resource files

Tags: php, html, cakephp, resources, response

I'm using cakephp 2.5.0-RC2 for a cloud engine in my local server (LAMP) and I was wandering if there is a way to use a video file as resource.  I'm using this for pictures:

```
class mycontroller extends AppController {
      function resource (){
          $fullpath = "/path/to/my/resource/file";
          $this->response->file($fullpath, array('download' => false));
      }
}
```

But the same seems not to work for a sound or a video file.

```
<--! this works -->
<img alt = "" src = "/args/for/my/controller" />

<--! this doesn't work -->
<video src = "/args/for/my/controller" ></video>
<audio src = "/args/for/my/controller" ></audio>
```

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is not a proper problem description, you should be a little more specific on what happens and what you'd expect to happen instead, what you've already tried to debug the problem, etc... Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Video and audio were not supported in HTML before HTML5.  Not all browsers support HTML5, and of those that do, they do not necessarily support all features of HTML5.  Your options besides using HTML5 are to use some sort of plugin to play the media, such as a player built in Flash, or to simply link to the file for users to download and play on their own.

Comment: OK, just to be sure it's not a servers side problem, I've tried to open the stream from an other app, VLC to be precise, and it seems te problem is still there.